# Convert ionic app to lazy loading

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

in the middle of work on an Ionic 3 app I started noticing that the app is a lil bit "slow"
so I heard about the "Lazy Loading" And I think it would be useful here..
the problem is that I already have a big amount of pages , so  I'd like to know, There is any way to Convert those pages to Lazy loading?

Another thing is the animation while changing pages, i made Card that animate in the page when I load it, but the animation is corrupted because the app is slow.. there is a way to make delay at the start of the page load so it would show the animation better?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend implementing the `lazy loading` on your app. It'll give a huge performance boost to your app. I'm telling these things using my own experience.

After that, you need to upgrade your app to `Angular 5 / Ionic 3.9.2`. That too will give amazing performance improvements and also very small bundle size to your app.

*References you may need for it:*

[**Ionic and Lazy Loading Pt 1**](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/)

[**Ionic and Lazy Loading Pt 2**](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/)

[**Angular 5 / Ionic 3.9.2 release notes**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/releases)

***How to upgrade to Angular 5 / Ionic 3.9.2***

*Step 1:* Change your `package.json` as follows.

```
"dependencies" : {
  ...
  "@angular/common": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.0",
  "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
  "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
  "rxjs": "5.5.2",
  "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  ...
},
"devDependencies: {
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.0"
  "typescript" : "2.4.2"
}
```

*Step 2:* Delete `node_modules` folder.

*Step 3:* Run > `npm i`

Comment: So I need to move between all of my pages and add this module?

Comment: You need to do little bit lengthy work here. Please read the 2 docs which I have shared above and after that ask any questions if you have.

Comment: Thanks, I will,
By the way I didn't understood how to update the Angular/Ionic.
just updated the CLI to 3.19.0 but what else?

Comment: Thanks man, Also tried to do the convertion and it didn't went well..I'll try again and let you know!
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Ok sure.. NP :)

Comment: Error: SG50\SG50\SG50\src\pages\Home\Home.ts has a @IonicPage decorator, but it does not have a corresponding "NgModule" at SG50\SG50\SG50\src\pages\Home\Home.module.ts
    at new BuildError (\SG50\SG50\SG50\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at \SG50\SG50\SG50\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\deep-linking.js:57:21
    at <anonymous>

What is going here?

Comment: Hope error says everything no? You need to create `Home.module.ts` file in your `home` folder.Hope you followed the doc which I have mentioned.It clearly says these things.

Comment: Can we have an `image` of your home folder structure and code of `Home.module.ts`?

Comment: Managed to make it work, but still the animation is laggy :\

Comment: Did you try on `device` using this `ionic cordova run android --prod --device`